# WAMP ERROR - #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, windows, apache, wamp

I have first downloaded WAMP server for 64 bit computer and tryed to start phpMyAdmin but the first error was: #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO).

After this i have created a new folder named "config" in wamp -> apps -> phpmyadmin4.1.14 and visited http://localhost/phpmyadmin/setup and created a new server. After this in my "config" folder appeared a new config.inc php file, then i have opened the old config.inc php file and copyed the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;` and inserted in the new config.inc php file. Then i have the old file renamed config.inc.org and the new config.inc file putted in the phpmyadmin4.1.14 folder.

After all these changes it allowed me to log in and i tryed to log in with username "root", i havent used a password, and then i clicked "go", then there is a new error: #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

**What should i do now?**

Comment: What colour is your wampmanager icon. It sits in the system tray.

Comment: Always green. I have uninstalled even skype to free the ports for wamp server.

Comment: Check the MySQL error log `left click wampmanager->MYSQL->Error log` Oh and you should not need to do anything to phpMyAdmin to get it to run. Whatever the issue is its not the phpMyAdmin default state

Comment: Skype can be configured to not use port 80 and 443 or just dont start it until after WAMPServer starts Apache. Then it will automatically not use port 80

Comment: Of course it could be that you have another MYSQL Server running on this PC, have you checked for that?

Comment: I tryed the wampmanager->MYSQL->Error log and there is a pop up: "Cannot find the D:\wamp\logs\mysql.log file. Do you want to create a new file?". Could that mean that there is no MySQL server installed on my computer by wamp server?

Comment: It is more likely that you have another MYSQL Server running. Look at the services snapin `Windows key+R` enter `services.msc` press OK button. WAMPServers MySQL is called `wampmysqld64` but do you also have a service called `MYSQL` running?

Comment: I have opened services.msc and there is no wampmysqld64 and no MYSQL service. It might be that the installation have failed on my computer. couldnt it?

Comment: But you said that the wampmanager icon was GREEN? So there must be a mysql somewhere. Anyway it will do not harm to reinstall WAMPServer. Do a uninstall, then delete `\wamp` folder manually. And then try to reinstall it.

Comment: It wont work. I have 3 times tryed a reinstall for wamp server. But every time it is the same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84703/discussion-between-riggsfolly-and-alanas-macijauskas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed. There was an another php service running on my windows that blocked the wamp server php service. So i just unninstalled the service which i do not need.

Answer (score 0):

For WAMP Users, something wierd happens to PHPMyAdmin.
Somehow it looses its php.ini file, so from wamp menu click PHP and then click php.ini
It will tell you that it doesn't exist? do you want to create it?
I said yes.
Then i copied a php.ini file from another PHP location and pasted the content saved and exit.
Then i go back to WAMP menu and i click localhost at top, loads the WAMP Server Configuration, 
then choose phpmyadmin from the bottom link, now login
Boom Worked for me :)